# How to get a list from a list?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

I read a pandas dataframe `df` from `.csv` file.
Each cell of the dataframe contains a string like the following

```
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.columns:

df[i][j]
      '[0.109, 0.1455, 0.0, 1.80e-48, 42.070, -14.582]'
```

I would like to have a `list` with the values as `np.float`. I tried

```
 df[i][j].split()
'[0.109,',
 '0.145,',
 '0.0,',
 '1.80e-48,',
 '42.070,',
 '-14.582]']
```

Comment: what about `l = [float(x.strip(' []')) for x in s.split(',')]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string as a list of floats:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[0.109, 0.1455, 0.0, 1.80e-48, 42.070, -14.582]')
[0.109, 0.1455, 0.0, 1.8e-48, 42.07, -14.582]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without exterior modules, it's pretty easy to do with a list comprehension:

```
A = df[i][j]                     '[0.109, 0.1455, 0.0, 1.80e-48, 42.070, -14.582]'
B = A.strip("[]").split(",")      ['0.109', ' 0.1455', ' 0.0', ' 1.80e-48', ' 42.070', ' -14.582']
C = [float(x) for x in B]         [0.109, 0.1455, 0.0, 1.8e-48, 42.07, -14.582]
```

So the one-liner would be:

```
My_list_of_floats = [float(x) for x in df[i][j].strip("[]").split(",")]
```

Comment: This has the added benefit to being easily modified in the case you run into slightly different formats such as a list of numbers enclosed with curly brackets or other small changes. It can also never be used to run malicious code.

Comment: True, it's also easy to add support for other languages, for example if the values use a comma instead of a dot as decimal separator (add in a `.replace(",", ".")`) and semi-colons instead of commas to delimit values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `eval()` function to convert the string into a python object, then turn into np.float objects:

`map(np.float, eval(df[i][j]))`

This makes the string into a python list first, then casts each item as a np.float.

Since `np.float == float`, you can skip the casting to np.float, and just do

`eval(df[i][j])`

Comment: You might want to include the [usual provisos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), and I recommend you *avoid* chained indexing. Instead, use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for fast scalar access. Note also to iterate columns you don't need to access [`pd.DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

for i in df.index:
    for j in df:
        print(literal_eval(df.at[i, j]))
```

If you need to apply this for an entire series, you can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or a list comprehension:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(literal_eval)
df['col1'] = [literal_eval(i) for i in df['col1']]
```

If each list has the same number of items I strongly suggest you split into separate columns to permit vectorised functionality:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col1').map(literal_eval).values.tolist()))
```

Pandas is not designed to hold lists in series and for big data workflows you will likely face efficiency and memory issues with such a data structure.